# Proof of the Sobolev Extension Theorem in Evans' PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

From PDE Evans, pages 254-256(1st edition) or pages 268-270(2nd edition).
In equation(9) of step 6  , Evans yields :
$$ || \bar{u} ||_{W^{1,p \,}(R^n)} \leqslant C ||u||_{W^{1,p \,}(U)} $$
My question is : $$ \bar{u} := \sum_{i=0}^{N} \xi_i \bar{u}_i $$is defined in $ \cup_{i=0}^N W_i \,\ , $  and has no meaning outside this domain. i.e. This is not an extension to $R^n$.
I can understand that
$$ || \bar{u} ||_{W^{1,p \,}(\,\ \cup_{i=0}^N \,\ W_i)} \leqslant C ||u||_{W^{1,p \,}(U)} $$
hold true, but why the domain here can be replaced with $R^n$?

Comment: Doesn‘t the function $\overline u$ simply have compact support in $\bigcup_{i=1}^N W_i$? Then we can just set the function to be $0$ outside.

Comment: @Eric Thanks Eric, this may be true, and I have thought about it. But what I cant understand is:  the complicated extension keeps the continuity along the boundary, if now we let $\bar{u}$ be 0 outsize, this again creat a bad discontinuity....  since so , why not just let the original $u$ be 0 outside?

Comment: But we constructed $\overline u$ in such a way, to be extendable to $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. That was the whole purpose of the construction we choosed.

Comment: Well...In fact such a $\bar{u}$ even does not belong to $W_{1,p}( R^n ) $ , just take example for $ n = 1 $ and $ u = 1 i,x \in (0,1)$. Its extension  in this way is $ \bar{u} = 1 ,x \in  (-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon) $ and $ 0 $ elsewhere.  I guess a mollification should be used to keep the continuity?

Comment: Your example misses that these smooth functions $\xi_i$ have compact support in $W_i$.

Comment: Sorry, In this example, $ W_1 = (-\epsilon, \epsilon), W_2 = (1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon ), W_0 = (\epsilon, 1 - \epsilon)$,  $ \xi_i $ is the corresponding Indicative function, and $\bar{u}_0 = \bar{u}_1 = \bar{u}_2 = 1$, so $\bar{u} = \xi_0\bar{u}_0 + \xi_0\bar{u}_0 + \xi_0\bar{u}_0 = 1,  x \in (-\epsilon , 1+\epsilon ). $ Is there any wrong?

Comment: @daw Thanks, I misunderstand " partition of unity " as " indicative function " . This seem to be a stupid topic, should I delete it?